# Json Path logical NOT operator with Filter not working

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I have JSON data and want to use the logical not operator in JSONPath, however, I want to use it dynamically since my input string consists of many filters which I convert into a JSONPath query.

`v1/movie?filter=not metadata.sample eq "NETFLIX"` this way I am using my APY. This should be converted to `[?(!(@['metadata']['PLM-CODE'] == 'NETFLIX'))]` using the Filter object of JSONPath.

Now this below one works perfectly

```
JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(jsonString).read("$.data[?(!(@['metadata']['PLM-CODE'] == 'NETFLIX'))]",typeRef);
```

but I can not directly add `!` when using the code below:

```
String stringFilter = rightPred.toString();
String notFilterString = "[?(!" + stringFilter.substring(2,stringFilter.length()-1) + ")]";
return Filter.parse(notFilterString);
```

but parse is converting it to `[?(@['metadata']['PLM-CODE'] == 'NETFLIX' ! null)]`

Comment: Have you tried using a `!=`?

Comment: != doesnt serve my purpose. that is relational operator

Comment: actually problem is in Filter.parse(notFilterString); method
which is Json-path own library method. but i am not sure how should i fix that or find alternative for that

Comment: Your doing `!(x==y)`.  Instead, use `x!=y`.  I'm not sure that `!(<expr>)` is supported, but I'm not familiar with that library specifically.  It's certainly not supported by JSON Path in general.

Comment: Are you working in Javascript? Which library you are using? Can you add a link?

Comment: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: !(x==y) this is not same as x!=y as this is not equal operator. and !(expression) is logical not operator. even this is working when we directly pass it to json path read method. but problem is with when we want to implement using Filter predicate